# UIScrollView not scrolling

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm loading a `UIScrollView` with `UIImageViews`.  imageViews below is an `NSMutableDictionary` of `UIImageViews`.  The scrollview is an `IBOutlet` with scrolling and paging enabled.  The loop adds two images.  However, I only ever see the first image in the scrollview and am not able to scroll.  Is there something else I need to enable for scrolling to work?

```
for(NSString *s in [imageViews allKeys]){
    UIImageView *myImageView = [imageViews valueForKey:s];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90);
    myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(120, 90);
    [scrollView addSubview:myImageView];
}

[scrollView layoutSubviews];
```

Comment: `for(NSString *s in [imageViews allKeys])` could be written as `for(NSString *s in imageViews)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your scrollView in IB is about 120x90? Then you'll need to set your contentSize to be at least 240x90 in case of 2 images, and (n * 120)x90 for n the amount of imageViews, assuming you want to be able to scroll/page horizontally. This is because the contentSize indicates the entire "virtual" area of your images.

Also: you're currently placing each imageView at the same coordinates:

```
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90)
```

This is why you only see one image, they overlap. You'll need to place each consecutive imageView at least 120 to the right of the previous.

Comment: I've commented out [scrollView layoutSubviews] and all works fine.  Is that needed for anything?

Comment: No, I don't think you need it here. I've only seen layoutSubviews used in cases like resizing animations.